# Map mouse click for one application

Tags: autohotkey, windows-7-x64

I'm trying the add the "play/pause on click" to the VLC media player using the AutoHotkey (v1.1.10).

I have managed to write the scriptlet which does what I want:

```
#IfWinActive,VLC media player$
LButton::
MouseGetPos,XX,YY
WinGetPos, , , WW, HH, A
if ((XX >= WW*0.20) and (XX <= WW*0.80) and (YY >= HH*0.20) and (YY <= HH*0.70))
{
    Send {Space}
}
return
#IfWinActive
```

But the script has a problem: I can't switch to another window with a mouse click outside the VLC windows anymore. All the clicks outside the VLC window (or more precisely: outside the bounding box) are ignored despite the fact that I have limited the remapping to the VLC window.

I have tried moving the `return` inside the `if`, but that has resulted in another weird effect: single click outside the bounding box acts as a double click.

Comment: Try the tilde prefix (~LButton::). http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols

Comment: @user3419297, it worked! Post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the tilde (`~`) [prefix](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols):

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

#IfWinActive, VLC media player

~LButton::
MouseGetPos,XX,YY
WinGetPos,,,WW,HH, A
if ((XX >= WW*0.20) and (XX <= WW*0.80) and (YY >= HH*0.20) and (YY <= HH*0.70))
    Send {Space}
return

#IfWinActive
```